# instance variable or static variable?

Tags: java, static-members

i hava a variable I want too use in 2 class. Must I declare it as static variable? can it be instance variable?

```
public class Text extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JTextArea t;
String s;
}
```

I want to use **s** in another class. Must I declare it as static variable? Is it possible to declare it as instance variable?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to use this variable for. Please share more code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't decide on whether a variable is static or not based on how it will be used. If it's common to all the `Text` instances, then it must be static. If each Text instance has its own `s` (whatever this poorly chosen name might in fact represent), then it must be an instance variable.

Answer (score 3):

`I want to use s in another class`

If s will have one and the same value throughout the application, then go ahead with static.

Instead if it is really a instance varible, you may have a reference to the Text in  other class and have a getter method for s in Text.java to access it

Answer (score 3):

You can declare it as instance variable and create a public getter method for `s`.

```
public String getValue() {
    return s;
}
```

Please also look at JB Nizet's answer on whether you should declare it as static variable or instance variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Text extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public static JTextArea t;
String s;
};
```

The above would make t available like this: `Text.t` outside of the class itself. You may want to consider inheritance if it applies in your case or using an instance to begin with, which is:

```
public class Text extends JFrame implements ActionListener{   
     private JTextArea t;
     private String s;
     public JTextArea getTextArea() {
         return this.t;
     }
};
```

and then use getters and setters to access their values, which is the Java way of doing things.
To use the above, you would now need to create an instance inside another class:

```
public class otherClass {
private Text theInstance = new Text();
JTextArea theTextArea = theInstance.getTextArea();
};
```

**Also, stop naming your variables s and t. It's a poor way to code. Use explicit names so that it's easy to tell what a variable is meant to do/used for.** Imagine you want to look at your code a few days from now, you may not remember what `s` and `t` were meant to do in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make the public getter method for s and use it from other class.